# Task.Factory.FromAsync never calls the end method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, factory

I'm kind of stumped and have been staring/debugging this code for hours now.

In my service I have -

```
var task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(
    AnotherService.BeginMethod(arg1, null null),
    AnotherService.EndMethod,
    TaskCreationOptions.None)

task.ContinueWith((antecedent) =>
{
    if (antecedent.isFaulted....)
    else // do something else
}
```

I have the above code wrapped in a `TaskCompletionSource` and set the result/exception in the `task.ContinueWith` method. So far, so good.

The problem -
As I'm debugging my unit tests (I have mocks for AnotherService), The begin is called, I store the variable and set the result on the tcs in my mock service. but my `EndMethod` in `MockAnotherService` is never called.

I assumed that the tcs returned from the mock service would get signaled when I set result/exception on it, causing the `From.Asyn`c call to call my End method. Is this not the case?

EDIT -

My mock implementation -

```
    public IAsyncResult BeginSetDevice(Device device, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>(state);
        var setTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {
                if (this.FaultedState)
                {
                    tcs.SetException(new Exception("You asked for a fault"));
                }
                else
                {
                    this.DeviceToReturn = device;
                    tcs.SetResult("success");
                }
            });

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Comment: `FromAsync` waits for the `IAsyncResult` returned by `AnotherService.BeginMethod` to be signalled. Could you show the code for `MockAnotherService`?

Comment: Added the mock implementation. I can debug and confirm that tcs.setResult is called and tcs status is changed to RanToCompletion

Comment: Everything in your question looks correct.

Comment: Never mind. I was missing a callback in my mock implementation.. That seems to fix it. Looks like the FromAsync method fills its own callback method. Thanks.

            

`if (callback != null)`
`{`
`callback(tcs.Task);`
`}`